# Remote Control on WTS 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-terminal-services, remote-desktop-services

When I try to Remote Control another user on a WTS 2008 server, I disconnect the other user and get a "Access denied" popup.

It's not a lack of permissions since I'm the Domain Admin. I think it has something with the W7 RDP client, but I haven't get any clue what to do about it.

Anyone else experiencing the same problems?

Comment: Can you confirm whether you're using Server 2008, or Server 2008 R2?

Comment: I'm using 2008 R2...

Answer (score 1):

There are a multitude of acknowledged bugs that pertain to this specific issue.  I have yet to get it to succesfully work on anything other than R2 with a W7 client with no multimonitors, but check out the solutions listed below to see if they apply to your situation.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2523307 and
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2484290

Comment: oops... talk about a resurrection

Comment: No problem :) Found the hotfixes myself :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the Terminal Server to allow remote control of sessions without prompting the user? This can be changed on the RDP-TCP object in Terminal Services Manager, or with Group Policy. If this isn't set, you won't get control until the user explicitly approves it.

Also good to know: starting with Server 2008 R2, Remote Desktop Services supports multiple-monitor connections. However, it's impossible to remote control a session that is using multiple monitors, so if you rely on remote control then you should disable multi-monitor support.

Comment: Yes I've set that option... To no avail :(

Comment: Is the client using the `Use all my monitors for the remote session` feature? This prevents remote control from working.